# How to avoid using "Object" as variable type

Tags: c#, object, dictionary

I'm implementing a dictionary in the following way to accommodate for an integer "key" and a Decimal/DateTime/String "value":

```
Dictionary<int, object>
```

However I recognize that setting the type of the "value" to "object" is not the safest approach. Do you have any suggestions for a better implementation?

Comment: If you want to store decimal, string, and DateTime in same dictionary, then `object` is your choice. But why you want to store such different data types? Can you tell more about what kind of data you are storing in dictionary? Maybe provide some dictionary sample

Comment: Do you *have* to store `decimal`, `DateTime` and `string` values in the *same* dictionary, or could you have different dictionaries for the different types?

Comment: I need to store them in the same dictionary unfortunately. Each dictionary instance represents a line in a CSV file.

Comment: @nic - Wouldn't it be better to create a class representing the structure of the line?

Comment: Thanks but no because I'm looking at different file formats and hence a generic solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concern might be at the wrong level. `object` probably is the right option for you if you want to store all those types of data in the same collection, but you're right to have concern.

Writing strongly typed code has a lot of advantages, because many of the checks will occur at compile time, rather than runtime. That means a lot of errors will be readily visible, rather than coming up during testing (which may or may not actually catch them the first time around). By storing three types of very different data in the same collection, you're inherently going to be losing the advantages of that strong-typing. That's why you don't want to use `object` for this, and by definition, any alternative solution that accomplishes the same feat will carry the same risks.

Rather, I'd say you have a couple of more reasonable options.

- You could reconsider what you're storing. Are you sure you need these three types of data in the same place? Maybe you'd be better off with three separate dictionaries, each with the correct type information. It's not often we want to *compare* a `string` and an `int` anyway, they're generally used in radically different ways.
- You could write a class that wraps the types. Have three properties, one for each type, then store some sort of null indicator in the empty ones. This still isn't a great solution, but it's better than `object`.
- You could investigate generics, and write a class with a single property to store the value, with a function to do something with it, and have that value typed as a generic type parameter `T`.

Storing it as an `object`, as you say, will *work*, but I'd say you'd definitely be better off to come up with a better alternative. It's hard to really tell you what to do, though, because we don't know a lot about what specifically you're doing.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll consider those options. I'm storing lines of a CSV file in instances of this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have different types in your generic collection, your generic type must be object.

Now, it could indicate a greater problem with your architecture. Take a step back and think about it. Maybe it would be better to have 3 dictionaries instead of one (a `Dictionary<int,decimal>`, a `Dictionary<int,DateTime>` and a `Dictionary<int,string>`).
Or maybe you can create your own class that will encapsulate your values.

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Wrapper(decimal d)
    {
        //...
    }

    public Wrapper(DateTime date)
    {
        //...
    }

    public Wrapper(string s)
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

and then use a `Dictionary<int,Wrapper>`. The good way really dépends on what your are trying to achieve. Having your generic type be object is often a symptom of a bad architectural decision at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Variable should have single use! Therefor instead :

```
var itemsObject = default(Dictionary<int, object>);
```

You should have

```
var itemsString = default(Dictionary<int, string>);
var itemsDecimal = default(Dictionary<int, Decimal>);
var itemsDateTime = default(Dictionary<int, DateTime>);
```

It is not duplication of code. If code is not used differently by type, then you could simply use `itemsString`.