# One line code of List<Dictionary<string, object>> to List<string>

Tags: c#

Is there a shortest way to do this. Because I want to get only a certain key from dictionary

```
   List<Dictionary<string, object> channel = DatabaseFunction.Select(some parameter);
   List<string> result = new List<string>();
   
   for (int i = 0; i < channel.Count; i++)
   {
       result.Add(channel[i]["key"].ToString());
   }
```

Comment: Why are you working with `Object` values?

Comment: For integer and boolean

Comment: You shouldn't do that: by using `Object` you're boxing those values (causing GC heap allocations) and you lose static type information. Consider using a `readonly struct` union-type instead.

Comment: Then, could you help me to do this properly?

Comment: Use https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf and change `Object` to `OneOf<Int32,Boolean>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303339/how-to-avoid-using-object-as-variable-type I found this answer may be useful for your case @JohnArnoldBarrozo

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, object>` - euww.. post the definition of DatabaseFunction.Select so we can perhaps give advice on how not to pull some huge amount of data out of a table only to throw most of it away. Your code doesn't compile, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) instead of `for` loop

```
List<Dictionary<string, object> channel = DatabaseFunction.Select(some parameter);
List<string> result = channel.Select(item => item["key"].ToString()).ToList()
```

You can have the `key` check before adding it to the list with [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) for safety

```
List<Dictionary<string, object> channel = DatabaseFunction.Select(some parameter);
List<string> result = channel
             .Where(dict => dict.ContainsKey("key"))
             .Select(item => item["key"].ToString()).ToList()
```

Comment: That's not what the green tick is for; you green tick *the answer you use* not the answer that was posted first. You also can upvote all (multiple) answers you find useful

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `"key"` *always* exists in *all* `Dictionary<String,Object>` objects in `channel` and always has a non-`null` `object` reference:

```cs
List<String> result = channel
    .Select( dict => dict["key"].ToString() )
    .ToList();
```

A safer version, which skips-over dictionary elements without `"key"` and/or when the inner `Object` is `null` would be:

```cs
List<String> result = channel
    .Select( dict => ( ok: dict.TryGetValue( "key", out Object? obj ), obj ) )
    .Where( t => t.ok && t.obj != null )
    .Select( t => t.obj!.ToString() )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `dict.TryGetValue( "key", out Object? obj ) ? obj?.ToString() : null`...